# selecting columns from dataframe based on list dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I Have a list of column names which changes dynamically, based on the column names present i need to select those columns from dataframe and concatenate it

for e.g

```
column_names = ['Year', 'State', 'Pol_no']
```

Dataframe:

```
Year State  Pol_no           Data Source1(sum)
2010     A       1                 90
2010     B       2                180
2010     C       6                270
2010     D       4                360
2010     F       5                450
2011     A       1                 90
2011     B       2                180
2011     C       3                100
2011     D       4                360
2011     E       5                450
2012     A       1                 90
2012     B       2                180
2012     C       3                270
2012     D       4                360
2013     E       5                450
2014     A       5                900
```

in this case i have to select year,state,pol_no column from the dataframe and concatenate it.

in other scenario it might be just two columns in list ['State'  'Pol_no']
then i will need to just select the above two columns from dataframe and concatenate.

any generic function which might help me do this

Comment: just index with them: `df[column_names]`.

What do you mean with concatenate them?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df1 = df[['Year', 'State', 'Pol_no']]
```